# Is it possible to get user id by userName?

Tags: facebook

I am building a small facebook application, in which I am performing the following:
The user fills out his friend's names (using friend selector), What I want to do next is retrieve the friend's user ID based on their user name. Is it possible? Can I query a user by its name and receive his id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because names aren't unique. What you could do though is capture the UIDs that the friend is submitting, because even though it looks like names, what he's really doing is picking out UID's. Then, even without your app being approved, you can query some basic data (first, last, locale, profile url)

Comment: I am using a control that holds the user's name, when trying to read the values it has got I get the string user names the user has submited. How else can I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's not true! usernames ARE unique too, but the actual name isn't unique!

The username itself is the part from the url e.g.: `www.facebook.com/zuck` (Page from Mark Zuckerberg) his username is *zuck* BUT not all user have set a username. For them it shows an userid e.g.: `www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123`